# MySQL Select into variables, return blank instead of null

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a before update trigger that has a large SELECT INTO variables statement which is returning NULL into the variable if the selected column is empty.

How can I make it return empty, ie blank, to the variables instead of NULL.

A sample:

```
If NEW.x <> OLD.x
then
SELECT
column_1,column_2,column_3
INTO
@column_1,@column_2,@column_3
FROM
table1
where NEW.x = table2.x
```

DB is MySQL 8.x

Thanks

Comment: ```SELECT COALESCE(column_1, ''), ..```. *empty, ie blank,* Use the term "zero-length string".

Comment: @Akina , I just figured it out. The problem wasn’t with that part of the trigger. I was using the variables in a select statement and that was returning NULL. The IFNULL function with the select statement inside fixed the problem.